# EF Core sending PK value on Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm getting an error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ScheduleTransactionLink' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

The SQL generated is:

```
INSERT INTO [ScheduleTransactionLink] ([Id], [CreatedByUserId], [CreatedDate], [Deleted], [LastUpdateDate], [LastUpdatedByUserId], [PaymentNumber], [ScheduleId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7);`
```

So obviously the issue is something related to passing in an `Id` value, and I have `IDENTITY INSERT` to on. But I'm not sending an Id.

My table is defined as:

```
internal class ScheduleTransactionLink : EntityAudit
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PaymentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Same as all my other tables. But only this bit of code is failing. As I can see, the generated SQL is sending 'Id'.

This only started happening after I added a navigational property to this table for a very complete query elsewhere.

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
      .HasOne(x => x.ScheduleTransactionLink)
      .WithOne(t => t.Transaction)
      .HasForeignKey<ScheduleTransactionLink>();
```

An example of how I save my entity is here:

```
ScheduleTransactionLink link = new ScheduleTransactionLink
{
    CreatedByUserId = _jwt.UserId,
    CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
    PaymentNumber = paymentNumber,
    Schedule = schedule,
    Transaction = transaction
};

_context.ScheduleTransactionLink.Add(link);

var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It's on the `SaveChangesAsync` where it errors out.

I have also added this code to `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ScheduleTransactionLink>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
});
```

Looking at the database, the table is created correctly:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleTransactionLink]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ....
```

How do I stop EF from sending the PK value?

Comment: on the Id Property, try `[Key]` instead of `[Required,Key]`.  I've moved away from attributes now myself and use the OnModelBuilding event & the fluent API so I may be out of date with attribute knowledge.

Comment: *I have INDETITY INSERT to on* - actually, it's set to OFF

Comment: Thanks. I tried @Jazb work, but the same issue. I have edited my question with the code showing how I save. Note that if I inspect the entity before saving, Id = 0. So I assume it's sending that. However, as I am using IDENTITY, I'd expect EF not to include the Id as a parameter when doing the Insert.

Comment: Does putting  `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` in the fluent, or removing the entire Id line from the fluent, correct the behavior? (Actually EFC should be able to set up an int called Id as an auto incrementing pk entirely by convention so I don't even think the [Key] is required)

Comment: Also I'm mildly curious as to whether the value of @p0 is 0 - if you turn on [EnableSensitiveDataLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.enablesensitivedatalogging?view=efcore-6.0) you'll see parameter values

Comment: Are you setting this table up to have a 1:1 relationship with Transaction? Just noticed the empty HasForeignKey call and I suspect it might be making EF put the Transaction.Id into ScheduleTransactionLink's Id - I think you need to be explicit if EF is making a wrong decision about which way round the relationship is. You can look to add a `int TransactionId {get;set;}` and alter `HasForeignKey<ScheduleTransactionLink>(stl => stl.TransactionId)` (or.. see if it works to just use stl.Transaction nav prop there)

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard - I think you're on to something there, as it was that code, which caused all the issues. I have reverted to my master branch, and all works... So I believe it's something there. I don't actually understand what that code that I have, does. It was guessing. So I will try your additional code. The ScheduleTransactionLink is a many to many link table.

Comment: Your suggestion of adding TransactionId seems to have worked! I'm testing now. But the error is gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that EF isn't able to fully work out how your 1:1 entities relate. It looks like it's grasped that Transaction is the principal but i suspect it's trying to forge a relationship by putting the transaction ID into the ScheduleTransaction.Id - that's an independent PK in its own right, not an FK of transaction ID.. You might have to help it out some by doing:

```
internal class ScheduleTransactionLink : EntityAudit
{
    [ Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PaymentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
  .HasOne(x => x.ScheduleTransactionLink)
  .WithOne(t => t.Transaction)
  .HasForeignKey<ScheduleTransactionLink>(stl => stl.TransactionId);
```

It might work to not add a TransactionId and just:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
  .HasOne(x => x.ScheduleTransactionLink)
  .WithOne(t => t.Transaction)
  .HasForeignKey<ScheduleTransactionLink>(stl => stl.Transaction);
```

..but it's not something I've come across/can test atm and the docs for configuring 1:1s do specifically have the "int Id property and nominate it in the fluent" approach. Give it a test, and if it works/doesn't let me know and I'll amend the answer